# Change variable names of an existing function at runtime

Tags: python, methods, parameters

I want to alter the variable names of a function i already defined. In the end it should look like this:

```
def f(a=1):
    return a

#insert your code here    

print f(variable_name_different_from_a = 2)
```

This code should print the number 2. It is ugly, but is this possible?

Edit: 
My question was indeed meant literally. In Python many weird things are possible and it is the weird things i often learn the most of. I also have a use case for this, but that one most probably can be solved less painfully.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: Why not just do "print f(2)"?

Comment: Perhaps you simply mean: `variable_name_different_from_a = 2; f(variable_name_different_from_a)` ?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: no. ;-)

Comment: @HeinzKurt: with all due respect, your question doesn't seem to make any sense. If you want a good answer, you'll have to explain why it is important to you what the parameter name is.  This sounds difficult, and there might be a much simpler approach to what you need to do.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: You are right, it sounds difficult. Thats why i asked 'but is it possible'. If the answer is yes, then i am excited to learn how. If it is no, then that also puts an answer to my question. But that does not make it senseless in my opinion.

Comment: @HeinzKurt I have no idea why you would refuse to further explain your problem when you have the free attention of experts who could help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the name of the new argument is known in advance**:

Instead of modifying an existing function object, which does not sound like a good idea (if at all possible), you can redefine `f` to be a wrapper around your original function:

```
# insert this code there
_orig_f = f
def f(variable_name_different_from_a):
    return _orig_f(variable_name_different_from_a)
```

---

**If the name of the new argument is *not* known in advance**:

The wrapper above can take `*a, **kw`, and manipulte them before passing them on to the wrapped function:

```
new_varname = raw_input('Enter var name')
def f(*a, **kw):
    if new_varname in kw and 'a' not in kw:
        kw['a'] = kw.pop(new_varname)
    return _orig_f(*a, **kw)
```

This works for any 1-arg function, when called using either positional or keyword args.

Comment: This is kind of cheating, as it redefines `f`. Unless it's impossible without doing so.

Comment: @AlexThornton what's wrong with redefining? unless you're taking the question too literally.

Comment: I'm just basing it on his choice of words: 'already defined'.

Comment: @AlexThornton it is much more plausible OP phrased the question suboptimally, than him wanting to modify an existing function object in place.

Comment: Although that does not solve the question when taking it literally, it still is a good workaround. And additionally I must assume that the answer to my question is a simple 'No'. So I accepted this answer.